# Column Naming Advice

Tags: sql, database-design, naming-conventions

I know there are other naming convention discussions, but the ones I saw were all general guidelines, I'm asking more for advice on good practice regarding my specific case. However, if there is another question that directly covers my case, please link it and I will gladly delete this question.

I have a database for modeling electronic devices, which contains tables such as Model, Unit, Brand, Manufacturer, etc. I'm wondering what to call the column that represents the actual textual name of the instance of that entity - as in "Canon" or "HP" for brand. Obviously, I could adopt the convention to simply calling the column "name," which I did at first. But then during a select, you are forced to reference the table names to get the columns since "name" is not unique among the selected columns:

```
SELECT Model.name, Brand.name, FROM Model, Brand
```

Which is ok, but then I got to the MobilePhoneFormFactor table and the Year table, the latter which stores accumulated data on a specific year. If I force myself to use the same convention with these tables, I get:

```
SELECT Model.name, Brand.name, Year.name, MobilePhoneFormFactor.name FROM Model, Brand, MobilePhoneFormFactor, Year
```

It seems a bit weird to refer to the year as "Year.name" instead of just "year." I could make this case an exception, but then I'm already breaking the naming convention I just committed to. So I considered this alternative naming convention:

```
SELECT model, brand, formFactor, year FROM Model, Brand, MobilePhoneFormFactor, Year
```

Here the Brand table has a "brand" column that is the textual name of the brand, the Model table has a "model" column that is the textual name of the model... etc. As shown in this select statement, this approach also allows me to conveniently drop the table name prefixes for columns in most cases (if you kept the table names, you get the rather redundant "`SELECT Model.model, Brand.brand, ...`").

But then what if I want to have a description field for each table? The obvious implementation is once again Brand.desc, Year.desc, just like my original approach to names. So this makes me think it's safest and most consistent to simply revert back to the Brand.name, Year.name scheme, even though it's a little weird in some situations.

A third option would be to name the columns "brandName, modelName" etc. but you might as well use simply "name" and always reference the table name in queries with "Brand.name, Model.name" in that case.

What do you think will be the best for my case? I'm not a database veteran, so I'm wondering what things down the road will make me look back and say, "it would have been so much more intuitive if I had just gone with Brand.name, Year.name" for instance.

Note: regardless of what I end up calling it, the textual name column (the natural key) is being used as an alternate key with a unqiue constraint; I'm using an IDENTITY column for the primary key.

Comment: Alternately, "BrandName","ModelName", etc... then you can have year just be year.

Comment: I originally addressed that scheme in my question but deleted it because I was afraid I was making the question to broad. I threw it back in there though since you and another person mentioned it.

Comment: I'm not understanding the Year table. There has to be a better name for that table.

Comment: Perhaps "YearlyData" would be a better name. It's data that applies to a specific year, but not a specific brand or device type (so it wouldn't work in any other existing table). We don't have the finer grain details of the data either, just the aggregate sum, and we need to store it somewhere, hence the "Year" table.

Comment: In fact, I think YearlyData would be good, because then YearlyData.year would make perfect sense. hurray. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with `name`.  I don't disagree that `Year.name` is a little weird, but IMAO it's worth it to always know what this column is called and not have to remember anything.

While we're exploring options, though, some people like to do like `Model.ModelName`, `Brand.BrandName`, etc.

I, of course, think they're crazy.

Comment: I concur on the crazy evaluation thing.  I've worked with some of the tables that folks like that generated; they're ridiculously bloated and frustrating.

Comment: Louis Davidson in "Pro SQL Server 2008" agrees, though he does use the table name + "ID" for the surrogate key column, because it is often migrated and it helps to retain the original name even when it's in the foreign table. Just thought I'd note that.

Comment: Yeah, I don't mind table_name + "ID".  It's also useful because it lets you do JOIN USING (tableID), where supported by DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

This is such a gray topic as you will find that there is no right or wrong answer but everyone has their own opinion and naming conventions.

Some general rules.

1. Be consistent.
2. Avoid repeating the table name in the columns.
3. Avoid SQL Server Key or Reserved words.
4. Be descriptive.  If you and/or someone else cannot tell exactly what data is stored in the column based upon the name then it is not named correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like repeating things, hence I would not use `Product.ProductName` (and don't use `Product.ProductId`, too).

Naming the column just like the table seems also flawed to me - `Product.Product`?!? If a row from the table represents a product, how can a product be represented by a single column, too? So I absolutly suggest `Product.Name`.

In the case of the table `Year` I tend to say that the name is not choosen very well - you are not storing information about a year, but something like an accumulation interval. Maybe call it `ReportingInterval` and then there is no problem with calling the column `Year`. And I don't think this violates the naming convention - it's just a column name like `Name`. If you really want a key column with the same name for all tables, you should consequently name it `NaturalKey` because you want a column with a specific function, not describing a common attribute of all your tables.

By the way, table names **must** be pluralized ... :D

Comment: Due to my OOP background, I'm in love with singular table names, so I don't think you can take that from me :)

Comment: (I think) Singular is right for the classes representing rows of a table, but it is not for a collection of rows. SELECT * FROM Product?!? No way! SELECT * FROM Products ...

Answer (score 1):

I usually alias my tables in queries, such as:

```
SELECT b.Name, m.Name, mpff.Name 
FROM Brands b, Manufacturers m, MobilePhoneFormFactor f  etc...
```

However I think MobilePhoneFormFactor is too long of a name; I would just call it FormFactor.

Comment: Using this convention, would you stick with it even to Year.name, or would you break the convention to call the column just "year" as in  "Year.year"? Year.name follows the convention set forth, but isn't as inutuitive to me

Comment: I'd have to review your specific case more, But i'd be inclined to say year should be some sort of constant, not a table by itself.

Comment: We use the Year table to store accumulated data (that we didn't accumulate ourselves) that isn't associated with any specific brand or device.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally go with the clearest column name that makes sense for tables, regardless of whether or not there is a collision of names; and when you do that, make sure that you explicitly state the table name before the column name in any select statement.

Such as:

```
SELECT Model.name, Brand.Name, mff.Name from Model, Brand, MobileFormFactor as mff...
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the Neil N, it's a good idea to use table names or aliases in any case when you are doing a multi table join to eliminate ambiguity.  Name your columns with names that make sense and then when you do multi table joins alias the tables and use the aliases.

Your table names should be as unambiguous as possible.  Shorter names are ideal but if longer names are required to reduce ambiguity then use the longer names.

Answer (score 1):

I always use:

```
SELECT ModelName, BrandName, FROM Model, Brand
```

If you use

```
SELECT Model.name, Brand.name, FROM Model, Brand
```

then you'll need to give each column an alias when you join up the tables in views, like this

```
SELECT Model.name AS ModelName, Brand.name AS BrandName, FROM Model, Brand
```

If you use fields like ModelID, ModelName, ModelDescription then you always know what you are dealing with when you join your tables up -- especially when you use aliases (which you should) and then have m.ModelName instead of Model.ModelName.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with the simplest scheme possible.  All schemes break down after a while and it becomes difficult to remember what or why you used something other than name and id.

I always alias my tables and use those aliases when I select the column.  My alias convention (and yes this scheme has its limits as well) is the first initial from each word in the table name.  So

```
SELECT m.name, b.name, FROM Model AS m, Brand AS b ...
```

and

```
SELECT m.name, b.name, y.name, mpff.name FROM Model AS m, Brand AS b, MobilePhoneFormFactor AS mpff, Year AS y ...
```

This keeps the naming schema simple and memorable and also makes the SQL more readable IMHO.  I also use explicit JOIN statements to distinguish table joins from filtering clauses in my WHERE clause, but that is probably getting outside the scope of the question.

Comment: I did the same thing. The problem comes when you want to build a view.
You have to give different name for yours colums named "name". I would like to restart form the beginning and apply the solution of Craig HB